# Percentage Difference Between Remote Directories

Tags: bash, ssh, diff, rsync

I am writing a script using rsync that synchronizes a remote directory with a local one without deleting any files. This is fairly simple, but I would like to be able to track progress, in simple terms without flooding a log file with the output of the `--progress` option in rsync.

To this end I was wondering if there is a way to easily (i.e. without consuming a lot of bandwidth) calculate the difference between two directories recursively. One directory should be remote, and the other local. We are looking for the amount of data that exists in the remote file but not in the local directory keeping in mind the fact that there may be data in the local directory that is not in the remote directory and we do not want that factored into the difference. Ideally, it should say something like: `Synchronizing /remote/dir -> /local/dir: 12MiB/24MiB (50%) Done`

If anyone knows an easy way of accomplishing this with a bash script that would be really helpful.

As always, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps do a remote and a local `du -s` on the top level folders first to get the totals to be measured against. Then you could use `du` on subfolders to get subtotals for percentages or, if the files are large, you may need to get the file length and use that as your unit increment.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work the way I intended because it would not account for the fact that files may exist in the local directory but not in the remote one which means that they are not part of the download and I therefore don't care about them for the purposes of measuring progress. Is there a way to account for this with du?

Comment: See some [discussion on global rsync progress](http://serverfault.com/questions/219013/showing-total-progress-in-rsync-is-it-possible).

Comment: That's why I suggested doing `du` at both ends.